# ClientResponse Failure in mockito test cases

Tags: junit, mockito

Iam working on mockito testcases positive test methods are getting executed but comming to Exception Test methods its failing with the Exception

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.apple.ist.retail.xcard.common.exception.InvalidArgumentException> but was<org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure>
    at
```

Below is the test method which is failing and its parent class containing client object

```
package com.apple.ist.retail.xcard.ws.exception;



public class TestActivatePrepaidCard extends CertificateResourceTestCase {

    public TestActivatePrepaidCard(String aMediaType) {
        super(aMediaType);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test(expected = InvalidArgumentException.class)
    public void testActivatePrepaidCard_InvalidArgumentException()
            throws DuplicateCertificateIDException, InvalidArgumentException,
            DupTxnRefException, AmountException, SystemException,
            XCardException {

        when(
                server.activatePrepaidCard(any(DiagnosticContext.class),
                        any(String.class), any(Number.class),
                        any(Amount.class), any(String.class), any(int.class),
                        any(HashMap.class), any(String.class),
                        any(SalesOrg.class), any(TxnRef.class))).thenThrow(
                new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid Argument ",
                        INVALID_ARGUMENT));
        client.activatePrepaidCard(certificateRequest);

    }
```

Its failing near client.activatePrepaidCard(certificateRequest); with ClientResponseFailure Exception
Parent test case is

```
package com.apple.ist.retail.xcard.ws.exception;

@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public abstract class CertificateResourceTestCase extends Assert {

    protected CertificateResource client;
    protected XCardServiceServer server;
    protected CertificateResource resource;
    protected CertificateRequest certificateRequest;


//  protected Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();


    private String mediaType;

    public CertificateResourceTestCase(String aMediaType) {
        this.mediaType = aMediaType;
        server = mock(XCardServiceServer.class);
        CertificateResourceImpl xcardServiceRs = new CertificateResourceImpl();
        xcardServiceRs.setService(server);
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(xcardServiceRs);

        dispatcher.getProviderFactory().addExceptionMapper(
                XCardExceptionMapper.class);
        dispatcher.getProviderFactory().addExceptionMapper(
                BusinessExceptionMapper.class);
        dispatcher.getProviderFactory().addExceptionMapper(
                RuntimeExceptionMapper.class);
        dispatcher.getProviderFactory().addExceptionMapper(
                BusinessExceptionMapper.class);
        dispatcher.getProviderFactory().addExceptionMapper(
                RuntimeExceptionMapper.class);
        dispatcher.getProviderFactory()
                .getServerMessageBodyWriterInterceptorRegistry()
                .register(new XCardTxnWriterInterceptor());

        dispatcher.getProviderFactory().getContextDataMap()
                .put(HttpServletRequest.class, new MockHttpServletRequest());
        client = ProxyFactory.create(CertificateResource.class, "/", new InMemoryClientExecutor(dispatcher));
        diagnosticContext.setReportingRecommended(false);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        Mockito.reset(server);
    }
```

Please let me know whats wrong in my code,I am pasting complete code so that I will not miss  any detail

Comment: It would be nice if you remove the parts of the code, which are not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: stefan,I removed unnecessary code is it making sense now??

Comment: As Stefan noted below, the exception here seems unrelated to Mockito or any general framework, and directly related to your business logic. I don't think StackOverflow is a resource that will be very helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is throwing an ClientResponseFailure. Debug your test and find out why. Use an exception breakpoint.